# Using the JGit checkout command I get extra conflicts

Tags: git, jgit

I am trying to checkout a commit using JGit. I am using the CheckoutCommand and I setting up like so:

```
CheckoutCommand checkoutCommand = git.checkout().setName(first.getName());
```

where `first` is the `RevCommit` that I want checkout out.

This fails because some files conflict.

When I run  `git checkout SHA1` , everything runs fine. In both cases, I am starting with the repository in the same state (HEAD is at the same commit).

I have tried using force by calling `setForce(true)`. This had no effects.

Any ideas on where I might be doing things wrong? I have an inkling it's in the setup, but I can't figure out where.

Thanks for your time,
-Caius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that JGit considered that the index was not clean, even though the usual git command sees it as being clean.

Doing a `git.checkout().setAllPaths(true).call();` before I try and checkout my commit seems to do the trick.